# Maintaining multiple data providers and migration approaches in SQL

Tags: database-design

Consider the synchronization of Basketball matches from an external provider. For this, I have two tables, the `match` table:

```
+----+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
| id |         date         | home_team | away_team |
+----+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
| 67 | 2021-07-28 19:45:002 | France    | USA       |
+----+----------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

and also an `external_match` table:

```
+-----------------+----+
|   external_id   | id |
+-----------------+----+
| 8e73rekk0lreppj | 67 |
+-----------------+----+
```

Now I want to bring in a second provider, which also has this exact match, but with different attributes, like the country, etc.. Then, the idea is to have an implementation 'switch' to be able to change at any time between providers. My solution is to update the `match` table in the following way:

```
+----+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+
| id | universal_id |        date         | home_team | away_team | country | provider |
+----+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+
| 67 | 62fef7b1770a | 2021-07-28 19:45:00 | France    | USA       |         |        1 |
| 68 | 62fef7b1770a | 2021-07-28 19:45:00 | France    | USA       | Japan   |        2 |
+----+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

and then the `external_match` table might become:

```
+-----------------+----+
|   external_id   | id |
+-----------------+----+
| 8e73rekk0lreppj | 67 |
| 18072481        | 68 |
+-----------------+----+
```

There is now an `universal_id`, which is an unique `id` for the exact same matches across different providers and also a `provider` column which is used to filter by provider. Notice the different values in `external_id` column, because those entries come from different providers. Then, to query all matches by provider:

```sql
select * from match
...
where provider = ?
```

and I think it works. **However, it's still unclear how to generate the `universal_id`**, and there are many more entities besides the `match` table, like `team`, `player` etc.. there must be some kind of data matching logic, right? but how is it typically done? and in terms of SQL?

Furthermore, consider some user related data that is indexed by the `id` column of `match` table. **Now, this content needs to be migrated to use the `universal_id` right?** otherwise it will only show if the 'switch' is set for one of the providers.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community It's a complex problem which most likely requires a complex solution. Reducing an already compact question to a complex problem is not possible. In bold you have the main topics.